# Trying to create 4 responsive equal boxes in center of page

Tags: html, css

Example of how the webpage looks like: [image]
So I tried doing this using flexbox. but I'm not very familiar with flexbox.
The goal is to have 4 equal boxes in the center of the page. Similar to the current frontpage of this websie: http://arma-life.org/#  (Scroll down to see the boxes in the section "For You').

I have tried looking at the current code, but the old designer did something and I can't seem to get that code to work on the new frontpage. It should be almost similar with the image, title and explanation. But the href can be dropped.

Can anyone point me in the right direction to do this please or help me out. I've litterally tried flexbox, align, margins, ...

It should also be responsive for phones and stuff. It should be underneath the HR.

Here is my current code:

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'open sans', sans-serif;
  zoom: 1;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

header {
  padding: 20px 0;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}
.container {
  padding: 0 20px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.logo-box {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
.logo-box a {
  outline: none;
  display: block;
}
.logo-box img {display: block;}
nav {
  overflow: hidden;
}
ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0px 10px 0px 0px;
  float: right;
}
nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 25px;
  height: 70px;
  line-height: 70px;
  transition: .5s linear;
}
nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  color: #868686;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
nav a:after {
  content: "";
  width: 0;
  height: 2px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 15px;
  background: #868686;
  transition: width .5s linear;
}
nav a:hover:after {width: 100%;}

@media screen and (max-width: 660px) {
  header {text-align: center;}
  .logo-box {
    float: none;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 0 16px 0;
  }
  ul {float: none;}
  nav li:first-of-type {margin-left: 0;}
}
@media screen and (max-width: 550px) {
nav {overflow: visible;}
nav li {
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
}
nav li:hover {background: rgba(0,0,0,.1);}
nav a:after {content: none;}
}
.A3L_Slogan, .slideshow{
  position: relative;
}
.slideshow{
    height: 600px;
}
.fadein img {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  max-height: 600px;
  left:0;
  top:0;
}

.slogan_hr {
  width: 960px;
  margin: 15px auto 15px auto;
}

hr.style14 {
  border: 0;
  height: 1px;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #f0f0f0, #8c8b8b, #f0f0f0);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #f0f0f0, #8c8b8b, #f0f0f0);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(left, #f0f0f0, #8c8b8b, #f0f0f0);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(left, #f0f0f0, #8c8b8b, #f0f0f0);
}


.A3L_Slogan {
margin-top: 20px;
margin-bottom: 20px;
text-align: center;
}

.slogan_title {
  font-size: 46px;
  font-weight: 700;
  padding: 15px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.slogan_catchphrase {
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}


@media only screen and (max-width: 640px) {
  .slideshow{
      height: 300px;
  }
  .fadein img {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    max-height: 300px;
    left:0;
    top:0;
  }
  .slogan_hr {
    width: 600px;
    margin: 15px auto 15px auto;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .slideshow{
      height: 200px;
  }
  .fadein img {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    max-height: 200px;
    left:0;
    top:0;
  }
  .slogan_hr {
    width: 560px;
    margin: 15px auto 15px auto;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .logo {
    max-width: 270px;
  }
}

/** features & articles **/
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(function () {
    $('.fadein img:gt(0)').hide();
    setInterval(function () {
      $('.fadein :first-child').fadeOut().next('img').fadeIn().end().appendTo('.fadein');
    }, 4000);
  });
    </script>


  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="logo-box">
          <a href="/">
            <img class="logo" src="images/logo.png">
          </a>
        </div>
          <nav>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="">Forums</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Rules</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Monetization</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Sign-up</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Staff</a></li>
           </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </header>
    <div class="slideshow">
      <div class="fadein">
        <img src="http://wallpapers.wallhaven.cc/wallpapers/full/wallhaven-159465.jpg" alt="">
        <img src="http://wallpapers.wallhaven.cc/wallpapers/full/wallhaven-160434.png" alt="">
        <img src="http://wallpapers.wallhaven.cc/wallpapers/full/wallhaven-150988.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="A3L_Slogan">
      <div class="slogan_title">
        Hardcore Roleplay Community
      </div>
      <div class="slogan_catchphrase">
        The next level roleplay experience
      </div>
      <div class="slogan_hr">
        <hr class="style14">
      </div>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can visi this codepen example. https://codepen.io/callado4/pen/ojPdvR
i hope this is usefull

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope this is what you want

```css
    body {
      width: 100%;
      margin: 0;
      font-family: 'open sans', sans-serif;
      zoom: 1;
      overflow-x: hidden;
    }
    .flexbox {
    display: flex;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
.flexbox .box {
    background: #0077dd;
    /* width: 150px; */
    height: 150px;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 40%;
    margin: 2%;
}
    header {
      padding: 20px 0;
      background-color: #ffffff;
      box-shadow: 0 4px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
    }
    .container {
      padding: 0 20px;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }
    .logo-box {
      float: left;
      margin-right: 20px;
    }
    .logo-box a {
      outline: none;
      display: block;
    }
    .logo-box img {display: block;}
    nav {
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    ul {
      list-style: none;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0px 10px 0px 0px;
      float: right;
    }
    nav li {
      display: inline-block;
      margin-left: 25px;
      height: 70px;
      line-height: 70px;
      transition: .5s linear;
    }
    nav a {
      text-decoration: none;
      display: block;
      position: relative;
      color: #868686;
      text-transform: uppercase;
    }
    nav a:after {
      content: "";
      width: 0;
      height: 2px;
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      bottom: 15px;
      background: #868686;
      transition: width .5s linear;
    }
    nav a:hover:after {width: 100%;}

    @media screen and (max-width: 660px) {
      header {text-align: center;}
      .logo-box {
        float: none;
        display: inline-block;
        margin: 0 0 16px 0;
      }
      ul {float: none;}
      nav li:first-of-type {margin-left: 0;}
    }
    @media screen and (max-width: 550px) {
    nav {overflow: visible;}
    nav li {
      display: block;
      margin: 0;
      height: 40px;
      line-height: 40px;
    }
    nav li:hover {background: rgba(0,0,0,.1);}
    nav a:after {content: none;}
    }
    .A3L_Slogan, .slideshow{
      position: relative;
    }
    .slideshow{
        height: 600px;
    }
    .fadein img {
      width: 100%;
      position: absolute;
      max-height: 600px;
      left:0;
      top:0;
    }

    .slogan_hr {
      width: 960px;
      margin: 15px auto 15px auto;
    }

    hr.style14 {
      border: 0;
      height: 1px;
      background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #f0f0f0, #8c8b8b, #f0f0f0);
      background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #f0f0f0, #8c8b8b, #f0f0f0);
      background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(left, #f0f0f0, #8c8b8b, #f0f0f0);
      background-image: -o-linear-gradient(left, #f0f0f0, #8c8b8b, #f0f0f0);
    }


    .A3L_Slogan {
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    }

    .slogan_title {
      font-size: 46px;
      font-weight: 700;
      padding: 15px;
      text-transform: uppercase;
    }

    .slogan_catchphrase {
      font-size: 30px;
      font-weight: 500;
      text-transform: uppercase;
    }


    @media only screen and (max-width: 640px) {
      .slideshow{
          height: 300px;
      }
      .fadein img {
        width: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        max-height: 300px;
        left:0;
        top:0;
      }
      .slogan_hr {
        width: 600px;
        margin: 15px auto 15px auto;
      }
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
      .slideshow{
          height: 200px;
      }
      .fadein img {
        width: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        max-height: 200px;
        left:0;
        top:0;
      }
      .slogan_hr {
        width: 560px;
        margin: 15px auto 15px auto;
      }
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
      .logo {
        max-width: 270px;
      }
    }
```

```html
<html>
      <head>
        <title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
        $(function () {
        $('.fadein img:gt(0)').hide();
        setInterval(function () {
          $('.fadein :first-child').fadeOut().next('img').fadeIn().end().appendTo('.fadein');
        }, 4000);
      });
        </script>


      </head>
      <body>
        <header>
          <div class="container">
            <div class="logo-box">
              <a href="/">
                <img class="logo" src="images/logo.png">
              </a>
            </div>
              <nav>
                <ul>
                  <li><a href="">Forums</a></li>
                  <li><a href="">Rules</a></li>
                  <li><a href="">Monetization</a></li>
                  <li><a href="">Sign-up</a></li>
                  <li><a href="">Staff</a></li>
               </ul>
            </nav>
          </div>
        </header>
        <div class="slideshow">
          <div class="fadein">
            <img src="http://wallpapers.wallhaven.cc/wallpapers/full/wallhaven-159465.jpg" alt="">
            <img src="http://wallpapers.wallhaven.cc/wallpapers/full/wallhaven-160434.png" alt="">
            <img src="http://wallpapers.wallhaven.cc/wallpapers/full/wallhaven-150988.jpg" alt="">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="A3L_Slogan">
          <div class="slogan_title">
            Hardcore Roleplay Community
          </div>
          <div class="slogan_catchphrase">
            The next level roleplay experience
          </div>
          <div class="slogan_hr">
            <hr class="style14">
          </div>
        </div>
<div class="flexbox">
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>

</div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Hi there, That is exactly what I want. How would I go about placing the images and text in there like the OP post. since it's for the same website.and if viewed on a phone. the boxes just become smaller. How would I make it that the boxes just appear below each other then, but a bigger size.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to create 4 boxes in 2 columns (with no need for flex) is to put 50% width inline-blocks inside an element and remove everything what may cause extra whitespace from parent:

html:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
        <div class="boxcontent">1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="child">
        <div class="boxcontent">2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="child">
        <div class="boxcontent">3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="child">
        <div class="boxcontent">4</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.parent {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1000px; // limit width for extra large screens
    font-size: 0;
    line-height: 0;
    letter-spacing: 0;
    margin: 0 auto; // to center on less than 100% width
}

.child {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 50%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 100px;
}

.boxcontent {
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 20px;
    background-color: red;
    height: 25%;
}
```

For mobile set child width to 100%;